# MAUI: Telerik RadEntry Style for Disabled is Not Working

Tags: telerik, maui, maui-windows

I'm trying to apply styles to a disabled RadEntry in my current project but the styles a not working. Is anyone here experiencing this? Below is my code.

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadEntry">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldTextColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource FieldBorderBrushColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,2"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusedBorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource FieldBorderBrushColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldBackgroundColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldBackgroundColor}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldTextColor}"></Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldInactiveColor}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldTextInactiveColor}"></Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="telerik:RadEntry" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldInactiveColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource FieldTextInactiveColor}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```